# Order of approximation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

[image]

I want to know what is order of approximation and how to compute it? I couldn't find a good source explaining order of approximation anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find that
$$
L[f](x_0,h)-f'(x_0)=C·h^p+o(h^p)
$$
where $L[f](x_0,h)$ is the difference quotient expression. Please compute the numerical errors, [Spoiler] it should be quite clearly apparent that $p=1$ in both examples.

$p$  is the approximation order.